# Compare each row of a matrix with the rest of the rows

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, processing-efficiency

I wanted to ask if there is an efficient way of comparing each row of a data frame with the rest of the rows. Currently I am running the code below but it is taking days to complete. To give more detail:

I have a table containing 166,000 lines (each line is an order), with 4 columns:

**Column1**: Order Number (primary key for orders)
**Column2**: Order Type
**Column3**: Customer Number (primary key for orders)
**Column4**: Date of Order

I want to identify the orders (not type **Z**) that were made within 3 days (>=0 and <=3) of making an order of type **Z** (by the same customer). So for example if I make an order of type **Z** today and tomorrow I make a second order that is not type **Z**, I want to identify that second order. Actually I want all the orders that were made by the customer within 3 days of the order type **Z**, that were of a different type.

The code I use is:

```
n<-nrow(data)
d<-character(n)
condition1<-data$OrderType != "Z"
condition2<-data$OrderType == "Z"
data[,4]<-as.Date(data[,4])

for (i in 1 :n ){

  if(condition1[i]) {  ## not type Z

  for (j in 1 : n)     {             

    if (condition[j])      {  ## type Z

    if (data[i, 1] != data[j, 1] & data[i, 3] == data[j, 3] ) {  ## I dont compare it with itself & from the same customer

      if(as.numeric(data[i, 4] - data[j, 4]) <= 3 &  as.numeric(data[i, 4] - data[j, 4]) >= 0 ) {

        d[i] <- as.character(data[i, 1])
                                                                                                }
                                                                 }
                          } 
                        }  
                     }
                  }
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide a few rows sample data in a copy/pasteable format (`dput()` is good for this). Also please show the desired output for your input - after reading your question I'm not sure what you're trying to do. The checks you make are explained nicely, but you don't say what your goal is / what you do if the checks are passed.

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way, but as a general rule to speed up loops, do as much work as you can *before* the loop. In your inner loop, you have 4 `as.Date` calls on entries in the same column. You're running `as.Date()` almost `4 * n * n` times! If, before the loop, you did `data[, 2] = as.Date(data[, 2])` you would only need 1 `as.Date()`. (I'm assuming your data is a `data.frame`, not a `matrix` - you should use a `data.frame` when you have data of different types.)

Comment: check `?duplicated` . I think you'll need to convert to `data.frame` first though, so maybe for matrices there's a better solution. I agree with Gregor that it's not clear what you want.

Comment: Order your data on `customer` and `day`. It will make comparison efficient. Not sure about your objective though still I think that `rollapply` with a custom function may help you.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the replies - much appreciated. I edited the document so that the problem is better explained. I also moved the as.Date before and I changed the format to a data frame.